# How would Einstein's later years have been different with modern computers?

Tags: soft-question, history, theory-of-everything

This is a historical question partly, and maybe too broad for this site, but would require some familiarity with modern physics research practice so hopefully appropriate here.

Einstein's later years, after general relativity, were (as I understand it) taken up predominantly by his effort to find a unified theory that explains both gravitation and electromagnetism and their interrelation.

And from what I understand his approach was mainly mathematical, trying variations of functions and so forth, looking for something that fit - and doing his work predominantly on paper.

Had he access to modern computers - programming languages, mathematica, etc. - how might that have changed his progress, and willingness to give up perhaps? And in what ways have computers in general changed / revolutionized theoretical & mathematical physics?